# Enter keyCode return 13 and undefined

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
(function() {
    $('.chkBtn').click(function() {
        check();            
    });

    $(".chkTxt").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
        var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        console.log(keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            check();
        }
    });
})();
```

If you type "enter" and press enter into the input the console show next keyCodes:

```
108 
69 
78 
84 
69 
82 
undefined 
13
```

Undefined, 13 return when you press enter.

Why this code return an "undifined" result?

Answer (score 3):

When <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed the `change` event fires before `keyup`. For that event `keyCode` is `undefined` because the event is not tied to the keyboard (it can simply be triggered e.g. by giving focus to some other control with the mouse), so you see `undefined` in the console.

After that the `keyup` event fires and produces the expected output `13`.

You can verify this by printing the name of the event in the output:

```
console.log(e.type + " gives the code " + keyCode);
```